# How to get values of map based on key?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a batch list object that contains batch numbers. Through `for` loop, I am sending the **batchNumbers** as a `key` for a map in my class. So, `key` contains batch number and `value` contains a list of jobs for that batchNumber.

```
List<String> batch = (List<String>) session.getAttribute("batchList");
for(int i=0;i<=batch.size()-1;i++) {
    jobMap.put(batch.get(i), ReportManager.getJobNumberForBatch(agent,batch.get(i)));
}
```

Now in jsp page, I need to show map's values based on the key. If I give `${Map.values}` we will get a list of jobs irrespective of batch. But, as per my requirement, I need to get joblist based on selected batch.

Could anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map.entrySet()`. The method will return a `Set` of `Map.Entry` from where you can get the `key` and the `value` of a particular `Entry`.

Using a for-each loop:

```
for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet()){
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

In your JSP file, if you are using **JSTL** taglib, using the `<c:forEach>` will do the trick:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    batchNumber = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value} <br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks Amardeep I got it but, could you please let me know how to display the same in jsp

Comment: Are you planning to use scriptlet tags<% -- %>? If yes don't do it and install JSTL and include this at the top of your page: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/`